# ad for dating service showing up when I go to view a friends pictures

Tags: ads, facebook-ads-api

Recently, when I go to view a friends pictures they have posted, an ad is showing up advertising a phone dating service. the picture shows an almost naked woman asking if you want to talk to her. If you click no, it still takes you to this dating calling site. when you click the "x" to close this box, you still get directed to the site.   This is no limited to just one friendm but to anyone of my friends pictures.

I have searched my privacy settings and do not see where to stop this from happening. It is very unappropriate advertising.

How do I get this to stop showing up? I went to show a child today a picture of a friend who has puppies for sale, and this showed up. This not something I want to see and of course children.

help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

it should be that you downloaded and installed something wrong? these type of ads are not the ones facebook normally shows, so maybe a test you should try is to change the browser and check if it shows again, you probably see that with another browser those ads goes away, if so... clean up the other browser from toolbars and things like this...